# Can I use RMAH without a credit card?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

I want to start using RMAH, but it says that I do need a credit card for it. I tried using PayPal, but still no luck. Even tho' my PayPal balance is sufficient, Battle.NET still asks for a valid credit card.

Is there any way to load a balance to RMAH without a credit card?

Comment: Have you set up your paypal correctly? http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/syncing-paypal-with-battlenet

Comment: @Samjus thanks for the link, but it says there: `You must have a credit card associated with your PayPal account in order to make payments or receive funds`

Comment: That is super weird. My paypal has my bank account set up and i've been able to do transactions on the RMAH,

Comment: And there you go.  Yes, you do need a credit card associated with your account.  Or, associated with your bank account.  Either way, Paypal has to have a way to pull money from *somewhere* for Battle.NET.

Comment: @fbueckert could not that *somewhere* be my PayPal balance?

Comment: What happens if there's nothing in your PayPal balance?  Blizzard is basically mandating that they get their money from a regulated, reliable source, such as your bank account, or credit card.  That's in case there is nothing for them to grab from your PayPal account.

Comment: Crazy. So I can get paid without a credit card but if I want to load money to buy stuff I need to use my credit card?

Comment: @fbueckert isn't bnet balance separate from PayPal? In this case they could make a loading mechanism that would require a transaction from PayPal to load the bnet balance. Well, anyway, that's some stupid system :)

Comment: It certainly is separate.  And, I agree with the system being stupid, but, hey.  You work with what you've been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load a balance, no. There is no way to load money into your RMAH account yet besides a credit card / purchasing money through Blizzard.

Can you make money? Yes/No. I say Yes/No since any money you gain if you use the Battle.Net RMAH money, it goes into your B.net account.